# Saving Java Print Method Generated File to MySql Database table

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8

I Need to save the printed Table into MySQL Database Field.

Table_Bill is filled before with another method using .addRow < It works Fine.

Then I need to Call this GetBill(); method from program and save the output to MySQL database.

```
GetBill();

private void GetBill() {

DefaultTableModel billTB = (DefaultTableModel)Table_Bill.getModel();

MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("** Sola Waves Reservation Bill **");

MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("**-----   Thank You !  -----**");

    try {
        Table_Bill.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, header, footer);

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

How to save "Table_Bill" in a MySQL Database Field.

Comment: Why? Why not save all the fields separately so they are actually usable? In fact you will need an invoice/line-item model.

Comment: @user207421 Yes I am. I just need to save the Final Bill as a pdf or image of a Completed Reservation into the database because after completion it need to be unable to generate the bill.

Comment: So you Rr now also asking how to save to PDF? One question at a time please. But what part of BLOB don't you understand?

Comment: @user207421 Tnx a lot.... I can use BLOB... I am still learning. Done it using BLOB.